# NuGet - How to configure package restore on MonoDevelop/Xamarin Studio

Tags: monodevelop, nuget, xamarin-studio

Reading [Using NuGet without committing packages to source control](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) I've understood I should add the `.nuget` folder to my project to enable package restore during build... and reading [Prepare a git repo for NuGet](http://wiki.team-mediaportal.com/2_MEDIAPORTAL_2/8_Contribute/Development/Code_Guidelines/Avoiding_Binaries/Prepare_a_git_repo_for_NuGet) I've understood I could remove `NuGet.exe` and `NuGet.config` and let the IDE download them automatically by setting `DownloadNuGetExe` to `true` in `NuGet.targets`.

Well, I'm a bit confused since 1) Xamarin Studio does not download neither `NuGet.exe` nor `NuGet.config`... and 2) the `.nuget` folder is not necessary at all since one could just issue command **Restore NuGet Packages** on the solution explorer and the packages are restored anyway.

Having said that, what's the right way to configure **package restore** on Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enabling package restore so it happens when the project is compiled is not possible using the NuGet addin for Xamarin Studio. It is something that I did not implement. If you want to do this you will have to add the files manually and edit the project to use the NuGet.targets file.

Personally I would instead use the Restore NuGet Packages menu option and not use the NuGet.targets file. One thing you lose here is triggering a package restore on every build however you only need to do it once. You also get some benefits of using this approach:

1. Your project does not need to be modified.
2. All NuGet packages will be restored before XBuild is run so any NuGet packages that have their own custom XBuild imports will be restored and available at compile time.

Comment: The NuGet team are recommending that NuGet restore should be used instead of using the NuGet.targets file. The latest version of NuGet will automatically restore NuGet packages when compiling without requiring a NuGet.targets file. So this could be implemented in the Xamarin Studio addin. The downside is that the addin would need to be loaded at startup to detect any build events. This is the reason I only added support for the restore being triggered via a menu.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the new package restore in 2.7. Just run

```
nuget.exe restore <your_solution_file>
```

to restore all packages used by the projects in the solution.

See http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore for details.

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't work on Mono, which is what OP was talking about. Package restore against .sln is specifically called out in the nuget docs as not yet working under Mono - http://docs.nuget.org/consume/compatibility

Comment: "nuget restore solution.sln" Works for me in mono with NuGet 3.3, but not for local (directory) based repositories. Of course local repos don't work for me from the GUI either so...